# Jinja template value not formatting correctly

Tags: html, format, output, jinja2

Please note, I have read the Jinja documentation, I have searched a lot for answers in stackOverflow and through Google search results. I have not found anything addressing this isssue.

--

Scenario: Calling a variable from sql dtatbase using python, then passing to jinja in an html file.

The python/sql
`

```
    user_id = session["user_id"]
    stocks = db.execute("SELECT * FROM  current_holdings")
    cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM  users WHERE id = ?", user_id)
    return render_template("portfolio.html", stocks=stocks, cash=cash)
```

`

The jijna/html for the problem section
`

```
                           <tr>
                               <td col span = "4"></td>
                                <td col span = "4"></td>
                                <td col span = "4"></td>
                                <td id = "cash">Cash</td>
                                <td>{{cash}}</td>
                            </tr>
```

`

The output of the problem section

Unexpected problem format as shown onscreen: [{'cash': 50000}]
Excepted: 50000

The same Jijna code (admittedly inside a for loop) works for the below code on the same html doc

`

```
{% for stock in stocks %}
                            <tr class="info_cells">
                                <td>{{ stock["symbol"]}}</td>
                                <td>{{ stock["name"]}}</td>
                                <td>{{ stock["quantity"]}}</td>
                                <td>{{ stock["price"]}}</td>
                                <td>{{ stock["total"]}}</td>
                            </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

`
This section successfully outputs only the values. Both sections are contained inside the

```
{% block main %}
```

Note on SQL: the jinja pulls from two different tables. the tables are formatted the same way and inside the same workspace and .db file. Other values formatted as NUMERIC render correctly.

Note on Jinja notation: dict.vr and dict["var"] have been tried interchangeably with no beneficial success.

--

Scenario: Calling a variable from sql dtatbase using python, then passing to jinja in an html file.
Unexpected problem format as shown onscreen: [{'cash': 50000}]
Excepted: 50000

Other Jinja code in same HTML file runs as expected

Comment: From your output: `cash.0.cash`. But best would be to correct your query.

Comment: But best would be to correct your query - elaborate.
I'm following the format of the documentation /courses I've learnt from. So if you know something I don't, the only way I'm going to get it is if you spell it out.

"From your output: cash.0.cash" - thanks for the tip, this fixed the issue.

Comment: You've cut too much in your code for me to give a proper advice on how exactly this should be fixed. What screams out of your code though is that you are getting a list of users while your query should return you a single user.

Answer (score 0):

The below code adjustment fixes the issue

```
<tr>
  <td col span = "4"></td>
  <td col span = "4"></td>
  <td col span = "4"></td>
  <td id = "cash">Cash</td>
  <td>{{cash.0.cash}}</td>
</tr>
```